# why is select query showing unsorted result in mysql cluster?

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-cluster

the query `"select * from table_name; "` shows different row results when run multiple times. Is this default behaviour of mysql ndbcluster ? Im currently using group by to sort the results

```
Version:-MySQL-Cluster-server-gpl-7.4.11 on centos 6.7
```

Comment: A database has no sort order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that the result is sorted by a column (or more) you must add the order by clause  (the SQL for default don't order the result)

```
select * from table_name order by your_column_for_order;
```